# Load balancing websockets on ECS?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm just starting to understand and solve this problem.

Node.js's Socket.io or Go's Gorilla websocket solutions have a connection pool per instance. So within each instance I can say "send message to client xxx".

However when I attempt to scale horizontally (by spawning additional instances), each instance has its own client connection pool, so trying to send a message to a specific client which is connected to another instance fails. I assume that's because the current instance doesn't have access to that instance's connection/memory pool.

I understand that ECS automatically scales docker containers horizontally, if I were to spin up a WS server project on an ECS and have it scale another instance to the service, does AWS handle talk between socket server instances magically - or must I handle that?

Comment: AWS won't stick you websocket sessions to a particular instance. Keywords to search: AWS ALB (supports WebSockets), SocketCluster.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN

> WebSockets are an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server.

That means that every websocket is a persistent connection to a specific server. In order to emit events to sockets that are in a different server you need an Adapter. For example if you are using Socket.io you can take a look at [SocketIO Redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis/blob/master/README.md).

On the other hand, to balance the load you can use an Application Load Balancer (ALB) which supports websockets and containerized applications in ECS.